# How to cast several nested interfaces - C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, casting

I have `IReport` interface. This interface is generic and has multiple properties, for the sake of not bulging the screen, let's say it only has an `ID` property and `T object`:

```
public interface IReport<T>
{
  public ind ID {get;}
  public T ReportedObject {get;}
  /*And more properties I want to see when receiving a report*/
}
```

Now, I have another interface which models some books on my db.

```
public interface IBook 
{
  public string Title {get;}
  public int ID {get;}
  /*and more*/
}

/*so I made:*/

public interface IReportBook<T> : IReport<T> where T : <IBook>
{}
```

I have an async method that gets the books from the database (and some more). I want to pass it an `IProgress` so I can monitor it:

```
/*In BookFinder.cs */
public async Task<IBook> FindThisBook(int bookID, IProgress<IReportBook<IBook>>) 
{ 
  /*Does somethings*/
}
```

Implementations:

```
//1) The book. This implementation is unique for the UI. 

public class UIBook : SomeClassIMustInheritFrom, IBook 
{
  /*This implementations has a lot of methods unique to it*/
}

//2) The book report for the generic book:
public class UIBookReport : IReportBook<UIBook> 
{
  /*This implementations has a UIBook property and an ID*/
}
```

My goals is to be able to pass, to the BookFinder, different implementations of IReportBook depending if I'm on console, WPF, etc.

ie:

```
/*in some UI script */

private readonly BookFinder;

public async Task<UIBook > PassBook(IBook bookInLibrary)
{
  Progress<UIBookReport> Report = new Progress<UIBookReport>();
  Report.ProgressChanged += DoSomething;
  var book = await BookFinder.FindThisBook(bookInLibrary.ID, Report); //<--
  return book as UIBook;
}

/*---------Again, here's how this method looks:---------*/
/*In BookFinder.cs */

public async Task<IBook> FindThisBook(int bookID, IProgress<IReportBook<IBook>>) 
{ 
  /*Does somethings*/
}

/*is there a way to just say 

IProgress<IReportBook> 
instead of
IProgress<IReportBook<IBook>>

? because all IReportBooks use IBook...
*/
```

The error I have is:

> ... cannot convert type 'X' to 'Y'... via a reference conversion,  boxing conversion, wrapping conversion, nor null type conversion...

What type of casting should I do? Is there a mistake or someway to simplify this whole thing? Thanks.

Comment: This design is fundamentally flawed, due to generic variance rules. Can you show how you are planning on calling `IProgress.Report`?

Comment: Yeah... I just learned about IProgress. This was silly (or borderline idiotic) I already solved it. I'm posting the way I did

Comment: Imagine you have a bowl of apples. It's a special bowl that can only contain apples. So you declare it as `Bowl<Apple>`. Now since `Apple` implements `IFruit` it might be nice to pass your `Bowl<Apple>` as `Bowl<IFruit>` to some funky helper methods. Here's the problem - if you could then some code might try to call `bowl.Add(new Banana())` and pow! You're adding a banana to a bowl that can only contain apples. Hence you can't cast `Bowl<Apple>` to `Bowl<IFruit>`.

Comment: Haha I've been reading about `in` and `out` parameters for 20min without being able to make heads or tails out of it and your comment lit a bulb in my head. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I changed 3 things.

1) I made a class that inherit from Progress

```
public class BookProgress : Progress<IBookReport>
{
  //Left it blank
}
```

2) made an implementation for IBookReport called UIBookReport

```
public interface IBook {}
public class UIBook : IBook {}

public interface IReport<T> {}
public interface IBookReport : IReport<IBook>{}
public class UIBookReport : IBookReport {}
```

3)

```
/*--------- in the ui*/

public UIBook PassBook(IBook bookInLibrary)
{
  BookFinder bookFinder = new BookFinder();
  BookProgress progress = new BookProgress();

  progress.ProgressChanged += DoSomething;

  var book = await bookFinder.FindThisBook(bookInLibrary.ID, progress); //<--
  return book as UIBook;
}

/*-------- In BookFinder.cs*/

public async Task<Book> FindBook(int bookID, IProgress<IBookReport> progress) 
{
  /*Do stuff*/

  var GenericBookReport = AppFactory.GetBookReport(/*some args*/);
  //AppFacotry is a script that returns the right implementation of some interfaces depending of the circumstances
  //In this case, it returns an UIBookReport (the class)

  progress.Report(GenericBookReport);
  /*more stuff*/
}
```